# Documentation of Navigator in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

When I am using `Navigator` from react native I am getting an error. The error is:

`Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

`Check your code at App.js:11.`

My code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  Navigator,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{ title: 'Awesome Scene', index: 0 }}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) => (
          <Text>Hello {route.title}!</Text>
        )}
        style={{ padding: 100 }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I followed this tutorial: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.43/navigator

Can someone please help me in this. Is there something wrong in documentation?

Answer (score 0):

This code example is from react doc version 0.43. [After that "Navigator" was removed](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigator).

If you do not care about backward compatibility then I would suggest following current documentation (0.63). In the latest version, there is more [simple solution](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation#react-navigation) is given.